# Context-free grammar for $\{1^i0^j1^k \mid i+2j=k\}$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

Suppose
$$L=\{1^i0^j1^k\mid i+2j=k\}$$

How can I construct a context-free grammar for $L$?

This is homework. Here is my attempt for the case when $L$ is defined with $i+2j=3k$ instead.

\begin{align*}
    S&\to aaaSc| bbbBcc| abBc| aabBc|\lambda\\
    B&\to bbbBcc| \lambda
\end{align*}

But it's not true because it accepts the string $s=a^2b^4c^3 \notin L$. How can I correct the above grammar?

Comment: The straightforward idea is to think in terms of PDA and then extract the LL-grammar from it. What is to be collected in the stack? How to represent these stack elements as nonterminals (a hint: they have constant derivations).

Comment: You should always ask the question you want to ask. If you ask a different question and someone answers it, and you then change the question, you make the answer look ridiculous. That's not a nice way to treat people who are trying to help you. Putting "edited" in the question doesn't help. (Also, you use $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}$ in the start of the question and $\Sigma = \{a, b, c\}$ in your proposed solution; although it's possible to guess what you meant, it's not as clear as it could be.)

Comment: Anyway, your second and fourth productions for $S$ are wrong. The fourth one doesn't preserve the condition (two $a$s and one $b$ cannot be balanced by any number of $c$s because $2 + 2*1$ is not a multiple of 3) and the second one is redundant with the first production for $B$.)

Comment: Hmm, it looks like I might have added mess to confusion by my edit.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution to problems of this form is usually to just rearrange the terms.

We know that $k = i + 2j$, which is the same as $2j + i$. So the language's sentences are of the form $1^i0^j1^{2j+i}$. We can regroup that as $1^i(0^j1^{2j})1^i$. (Parentheses used only for grouping.)

You should be able to just read the grammar off of that.

Comment: I edit my question:). 3k=i+2j.

Comment: @All Its problematic to change the question after it has been answered

Comment: Can you give me some hint about this case that $3k=i+2j$?

Comment: Assume another condition: i and j are divisible by 3. So you start with S, replace S with 111 S 1 any number of times,  then replace with T, then replace T with 000 T 11 any number of times, and remove the T. Then you handle the cases where you have I = j = 1 or I = 1 = 2 leftover.